# Java JXTA - where is the JAR file?

Tags: file, jar, jxta

Where can I download JXTA/JXSE? I mean the JAR file of this library, because I found project code here
http://java.net/projects/jxta-jxse/sources/svn/show
downloaded by SVN and I have no idea how to link all classes this to NetBeans.
any help please?

Answer (score 1):

See [this download page](http://jxse.kenai.com/Downloads/Downloads.html). You can manually download artifacts/jars from there.